# Javascript: How can I enable a radio button when 15 other radio buttons are checked with the same class?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to enable a radio button after 15 other radio buttons (code snippet below) are clicked. How can I do this in pure JS (no jQuery)?

```
<div class="assessment-question">
  <span><em>{% trans "I do more than what's expected of me" %}</em></span>
  <ul class="assessment-answer-list">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="question11" value="0-0" class="assess_answers" required> {% trans 'Never' %}
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="question11" value="1-0" class="assess_answers"> {% trans 'Rarely' %}
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="question11" value="2-1" class="assess_answers"> {% trans 'Sometimes' %}
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="question11" value="3-1" class="assess_answers"> {% trans 'Often' %}
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="question11" value="4-1" class="assess_answers"> {% trans 'Always' %}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="assessment-question">
  <span><em>{% trans 'I feel comfortable around people' %}</em></span>
  <ul class="assessment-answer-list">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="question12" value="0-0" class="assess_answers" required> {% trans 'Never' %}
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="question12" value="1-0" class="assess_answers"> {% trans 'Rarely' %}
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="question12" value="2-1" class="assess_answers"> {% trans 'Sometimes' %}
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="question12" value="3-1" class="assess_answers"> {% trans 'Often' %}
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="question12" value="4-1" class="assess_answers"> {% trans 'Always' %}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I currently have a "next" radio button that is disabled and I want to enable it after all 15 of the above (only a few shown) are checked. They all have the same class name so I can identify them under the same umbrella.

I have tried a couple of solutions that have not worked. The solutions I have tried all seem to need to have a function activated when each radio button is checked.

Can I use `addEventListener` or something?

Comment: there is only 10 radio-buttons in your code, not 15. And what are you talking about disable.enable which radio-button ??!!

Comment: @MisterJojo - In case you missed it, I said "snippet", not all 15 of them... Even said "(only a few shown)". Read the whole post before commenting, please. Pretty unproductive comment. Anyway, I am trying to ENABLE a button (clearly not listed) after counting that <b>15 buttons are clicked</b>.

Comment: you mean <b>15 radio buttons group  have a value</b> ?  because this all you have to do unchecked radio button group has no value

Comment: @MisterJojo if you go back and look at the snippet, you'll see they all have values. When all 15 are `clicked = true`. Stop picking a silly argument, I'm done responding to you.

Comment: mForm.question12.value = element clicked value, where are you come from !

Answer (score 3):

just use  the document.getElementsByClassName to get them all, keep track of the values (AKA, check if all of the values are true with a function), add a few eventlisteners for when it is checked, then once its clicked etc, then check them all to see if the value of all is true. For example:

```
var checkedBoxes = Array.apply(null,document.getElementsByClassName("myClassName"));
checkedBoxes.forEach(x => {
    x.addEventListener("click", onActive);
    x.addEventListener("focus", onActive);
    x.addEventListener("blur", onActive);
    //other event listeeners
});
function checkAll() {
     return !checkedBoxes.find(x => !x.checked) //can't find any radio button whose value is false, which means they are all true, which means they are all checked
}
function onActive(e) {
    if(checkAll()) {
        //activate next button
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a thoughtful response and commenting your code in the solution posted.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this real snippet to see how to do

```js
const myForm  = document.getElementById('my-form')
  ,   gRnames = [...new Set([...myForm.elements].filter(n=>(n.type==='radio')).map(n=>n.name))]
  ;
function SetButtonNextOnOff()
  {
  let answers = gRnames.reduce((tot,el)=>tot+=myForm[el].value===''?0:1,0)
  myForm.bt_next.disabled = (answers!=gRnames.length)
  }
SetButtonNextOnOff()
  ;
myForm.oninput = SetButtonNextOnOff  
  ;
myForm.onsubmit =e=>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.clear()
  Array.from(new FormData(myForm),e=>console.log(e[0],'->',e[1]))
  myForm.reset()
  }
myForm.onreset =_=>{ myForm.bt_next.disabled = true }
  ;
```

```css
label { display:block; }
fieldset { margin:1em; width:23em; }
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  width: 30% !important;
  top: 0; left: 70% !important;
}
```

```html
<form action="xxx" id="my-form" >
  <fieldset>
    <legend>I do more than what's expected of me </legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question11" value="0-0"> Never     </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question11" value="1-0"> Rarely    </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question11" value="2-1"> Sometimes </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question11" value="3-1"> Often     </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question11" value="4-1"> Always    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>I feel comfortable around people</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question12" value="0-0"> Never     </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question12" value="1-0"> Rarely    </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question12" value="2-1"> Sometimes </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question12" value="3-1"> Often     </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question12" value="4-1"> Always    </label>
  </fieldset>

  <button name="bt_next" type="submit">Next</button>
  <button type="reset">reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. I am appreciate of this and will try it out in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all 15 radio buttons to be checked, their name property should be different than one another

Each radio element should have click/change event and function defined for the event to identify whether it's clicked or not

Each time the radio button clicked, check whether it's enabled / disabled and update counter for the required no of radio buttons clicked accordingly.

Compare it with the no of radio buttons with the same class(getElementsByClassName())

if count is same means all required radio buttons are enabled, you can manually enable the next radio button in the event function

Comment: It was unclear in the post, but the ones with the same name are meant to be like that so only 1 of the group may be clicked. Thank you for your answer, though. I will give it a try.

Comment: Yes correct, the one with same names are in same group.all the best